# Не получается отсортировать и отрендерить в блок информацию

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

У меня есть масив обьектов

```
const infoBus = [
        { numberOfBus: 1, nameOfBus: 'Bogdan', amountOfPlaces: 30, numberOfWay: 1, startBusTrip: 'Odessa', endtBusTrip: 'Kyiv', sequenceOfStops: ['Berdichev', '   ', 'Kozatyn', '  ', 'Xmilnik'], costOfTrip: 15 },
        { numberOfBus: 2, nameOfBus: 'ZIL', amountOfPlaces: 32, numberOfWay: 22, startBusTrip: 'Kozatyn', endtBusTrip: 'Dnipro', sequenceOfStops: ['Poltava', '   ', 'Lviv', '  ', 'Kerch'], costOfTrip: 75 },
        { numberOfBus: 3, nameOfBus: 'Kraz', amountOfPlaces: 40, numberOfWay: 36, startBusTrip: 'Yampil', endtBusTrip: 'Rogatin', sequenceOfStops: ['Oskolez', '   ', 'Mykachevo', '  ', 'Feodosia'], costOfTrip: 89 },
        { numberOfBus: 4, nameOfBus: 'Honda', amountOfPlaces: 25, numberOfWay: 41, startBusTrip: 'Odessa', endtBusTrip: 'CHOP', sequenceOfStops: ['BAR', '   ', 'Sevastopol', '  ', 'Donetsk'], costOfTrip: 34 },
        { numberOfBus: 5, nameOfBus: 'Porshe', amountOfPlaces: 15, numberOfWay: 51, startBusTrip: 'Kramatorsk', endtBusTrip: 'Xarkiv', sequenceOfStops: ['Gaysun', '   ', 'Alyshta', '  ', 'Lugansk'], costOfTrip: 63 },
    ]
```

Мне нужно отсортировать и отрендерить в блок только те объекты которые имеют свойство **startBusTrip: 'Odessa'**.

Я подключаю хук useState таким способом

```
const [resultCities, setCity] = useState([]);
```

Хочу сортировать таким способом:

```
const getSortCity = (arr, city) => {
       setCity(arr => {
           for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
               if(resultCities.startBusTrip === city) {
                    resultCities.push(arr[index])
               }
           }
       })
   }
```

Проблема в том что я не знаю как через Хук отсортировать и сразу отрисовать в этот блок

```
<div className="request__container">
   <div id="request">
                        
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю в таком случае `useState` и не нужен, если нет необходимости хранить отсортированные данные в стейте

```
 const infoBus = [
      { numberOfBus: 1, nameOfBus: 'Bogdan', amountOfPlaces: 30, numberOfWay: 1, startBusTrip: 'Odessa', endtBusTrip: 'Kyiv', sequenceOfStops: ['Berdichev', '   ', 'Kozatyn', '  ', 'Xmilnik'], costOfTrip: 15 },
      { numberOfBus: 2, nameOfBus: 'ZIL', amountOfPlaces: 32, numberOfWay: 22, startBusTrip: 'Kozatyn', endtBusTrip: 'Dnipro', sequenceOfStops: ['Poltava', '   ', 'Lviv', '  ', 'Kerch'], costOfTrip: 75 },
      { numberOfBus: 3, nameOfBus: 'Kraz', amountOfPlaces: 40, numberOfWay: 36, startBusTrip: 'Yampil', endtBusTrip: 'Rogatin', sequenceOfStops: ['Oskolez', '   ', 'Mykachevo', '  ', 'Feodosia'], costOfTrip: 89 },
      { numberOfBus: 4, nameOfBus: 'Honda', amountOfPlaces: 25, numberOfWay: 41, startBusTrip: 'Odessa', endtBusTrip: 'CHOP', sequenceOfStops: ['BAR', '   ', 'Sevastopol', '  ', 'Donetsk'], costOfTrip: 34 },
      { numberOfBus: 5, nameOfBus: 'Porshe', amountOfPlaces: 15, numberOfWay: 51, startBusTrip: 'Kramatorsk', endtBusTrip: 'Xarkiv', sequenceOfStops: ['Gaysun', '   ', 'Alyshta', '  ', 'Lugansk'], costOfTrip: 63 },
    ]
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="request__container">
          <div id="request">
            {infoBus.map((item) => 
              item.startBusTrip === 'Odessa' ? (
                <div>{item.nameOfBus}</div>
             ) : '')
            }
          </div>
        </div>   
      );
    }
```

P.S. Ссылка на песочницу https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-aryabhata-1udnz?file=/src/App.js